# Combining two results in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to combine the result of two `MATCH` statements.
for example like this

```
MATCH (a)-[:connection]-(b:labelB)
WHERE a.id IN $selection
WITH COLLECT(a) + COLLECT(b) AS selection
```

However, the issue with this is that it produces a list of type `List<node>` instead of `node`. This is an issue because it does not enable another `MATCH` statement using `selection`.
Meaning this would not be possible as a continuation to the query:

```
MATCH (selection)-[]-(c)
RETURN c
```

This behavior can be achieved by a `UNION` but it seems to behave unexpectedly when using the result of the first `MATCH` in the second `MATCH`.

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE a.id IN $selection
RETURN a AS selection
UNION
MATCH (a)-[]-(b)
RETURN b AS selection
```

How can I combine two Nodes into a single value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNWIND which is similar to a WHILE looping in sql.

```
MATCH (a)-[:connection]-(b:labelB)
WHERE a.id IN $selection
WITH COLLECT(a) + COLLECT(b) AS selections
UNWIND selections as selection
MATCH (selection)-[]-(c)
RETURN c
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just replace this:

```
MATCH (selection)-[]-(c)
```

with this:

```
MATCH (s)--(c)
WHERE s IN selection
```

*By the way, I should point out that your first query will cause `selection` to have duplicate nodes if it is possible for a `connection` to connect 2 `labelB` nodes.*